# Issue converting filter data from excel to google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am using the below filter formula in excel to evaluate a dataset and return the lowest available value.  However when I try to use this formula in google sheets I am getting "No matches are found in FILTER evaluation."  From what I've read it has something to do with the way each program uses the formulas, but I've been unable to find a fix for google sheets that would accomplish the same thing.  Can anyone tell me how to translate this formula to sheets?  Thanks!

=FILTER($B$2:$B$20,$A$2:$A$20=SMALL(XLOOKUP(O2:AZ2,$B$2:$B$20,$A$2:$A$20,""),L2))

I'm trying to create a relative ranking structure based on cell values within a repeating range.

I have ranked the text values accordingly.
[Text Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D0FH.png)

I then have a sheet with columns that contain subsets of these text values like so; [Values Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXwu0.png)

What I am trying to accomplish, is that when a Rank of 1 is entered into a cell in row A, it will return the highest value of that row based on the column values in row B. So as an example;

If 1 was entered into cell A2, it would return "Text 1" in B2. If 2 was entered in A2 it would return "Text 3" in B2. If 3 was entered in A2 it would return "text 5". If any other rank (4-20) was entered B2 would remain blank. The same would happen in Row 3 except it would consider "Text 2" as rank 1, "Text 3" as rank 2, and "Text 4" as rank 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked each function has the arguments in the same places? if the order is different then it will fail. expecting a formula written for excel is "just going to work" is a long hope.

Comment: `XLOOKUP` is not available to `google-sheet`. Put some sample data here with your expected output.

Comment: Sorry I should have known better then to think there would be an easy 1 for 1 swap, I went ahead and edited up top with the goal here.  Any help would be much appreciated!